# How to display an image in a canvas object in tkinter using the path obtained from file browser

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, python-3.5, python-imaging-library

The create_image command is showing an error for the path I am browsing for the image and passing to the image parameter of the command,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\SAURAV
>   DAS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\projects\classify_gui.py",
>   line 29, 
> in module
>       cv.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_image'

Is there any other way I may be able to browse for the path of the image and display it, as in

1. Change the method of browsing for the path of the image
2. or, Change the method of displaying the image in the canvas object

   I am using Python 3.5 on Windows 10. I have installed all the pre-requisite libraries mentioned in the code. All the images being used by me are in the working directory as my project.
   Please help...

   ```
   import sys
   import tkinter as tk
   from PIL import Image,ImageTk,ImageFilter,ImageOps


   global fname
   fname = "images.png"


   def browse_file():
       fname = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Bitmap files", "*.bmp"), ("JPEG files", "*.jpg"), ("PNG files", "*.png"), ("All files", "*")))
       print(fname)
       return

   def classify_obj():
       print("In Development")
       return


   root = tk.Tk()
   root.wm_title("Classify Image")

   broButton = tk.Button(master=root, text='Browse', height=2, width=8, command=browse_file).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=2, pady=2)

   frame1 = tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=400, bd=2).grid(row=1, column=0)
   im = Image.open(fname)
   photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
   cv = tk.Canvas(frame1, height=390, width=490, background="white", bd=1, relief=tk.RAISED).grid(row=1,column=0)
   cv.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw')

   claButton = tk.Button(master=root, text='Classify', height=2, width=10, command=classify_obj).grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)

   frame2 = tk.Frame(root, width=500, height=400, bd=1).grid(row=1, column=1)
   cv = tk.Canvas(frame2, height=390, width=490, bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN).grid(row=1,column=1)

   tk.mainloop()
   ```

Comment: Did my answer fix your  AttributeError?

Comment: yes, it did. Thanks for that by the way

Comment: Allright. Then please select the green check box next to my answer to show your problem has been solved.

Comment: I did select the tick on the previous question... The tkinter one

Comment: That is a different question. I am talking about this question and the answer I provided below :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The methods in the grid manager will not return the widget. 
So don't place the grid methods at the end of a your widget. 
Instead configure the grid after the widget is created.

Change this:

```
cv = tk.Canvas(frame1, height=390, width=490, background="white", bd=1, relief=tk.RAISED).grid(row=1,column=0)
cv.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw')
```

To this:

```
cv = tk.Canvas(frame1, height=390, width=490, background="white", bd=1, relief=tk.RAISED)
cv.grid(row=1,column=0)
cv.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw')
```

Comment: Thanks it worked... Can you please explain me why my method wasn't working on only this command but every other command.

Comment: With `grid()` at the end of your widget creation any time something would try to interact with that widget the `grid()` would return None. So you get an attribute error because grid returns no attribute. Using `.grid()` at the end of a widget is fine as long as you are not going to be interacting with that widget after its created. Otherwise you should define the grid after the widget is made.